# Proof that isomorphism preserves powers of a group, using induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

The proof is about a property of isomorphisms between groups. Other properties were already given:

- a) $\phi(e_G) = e_H$ (Preservation of the identity)
- b) $\phi(g^{-1}) = (\phi(g))^{-1}$ (Preservation of inverses)
- c) $\phi( x \circ y) =  \phi(x) * \phi(y)$ (Preservation of structure)

Now the goal is to prove another property, preservation of powers:

> $\phi(g^n) = (\phi(g))^n$, for all $g \in G$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Here's my try, was a bit difficult to get it right with the induction for negative powers.

---

Let $g \in G$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $P(n)$ be the statement $\phi(g^n) = (\phi(g))^n$.

**Case $n = 0$:**

\begin{align*}
\phi(g^0) &= (\phi(g))^0 \\
\phi(e_G) &= e_H 
\end{align*}

Since the $0$-power of any group element is the identity element. The equality holds because of a).

Prove the remaining cases by induction on $k = 1, 2, ...$. Base case was already established, $P(0)$ is true. For purpose of induction, assume $P(k)$ is true, that is:

$$\phi(g^k) = (\phi(g))^k$$

**Case $n \ge 0$:**

We want to show that $P(k+1)$ is true, that is:

$$\phi(g^{k+1}) = (\phi(g))^{k+1}$$

Now:

\begin{align}
\phi(g^k) &= (\phi(g))^k \\
\phi(g^k) * \phi(g) &= (\phi(g))^k * \phi(g) \\
\phi(g^{k+1}) &= (\phi(g))^{k+1}
\end{align}

The last manipulation is valid because of c). This shows $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$, hence $P(n)$ is true for $n \ge 0$.

**Case $n \le 0$:**

We want to show that $P(k-1)$ is true, that is:

$$\phi(g^{k-1}) = (\phi(g))^{k-1}$$

Now:

\begin{align}
\phi(g^k) &= (\phi(g))^k \\
\phi(g^k) * (\phi(g))^{-1} &= (\phi(g))^k * (\phi(g))^{-1} \\
\phi(g^k) * \phi(g^{-1}) &= (\phi(g))^k * (\phi(g))^{-1} \\
\phi(g^{k-1}) &= (\phi(g))^{k-1}
\end{align}

The last two manipulations are valid because of b) and c). This shows $P(k) \implies P(k-1)$, hence $P(n)$ is true for $n \le 0$.

We established that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

Any comments on the form? Is it acceptable here to use induction twice?

Comment: Homomorphisms have this property.  You don't need an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is good. However, you can shorten it if you know (or have proven) that for any $g \in G$ and $n \in \Bbb{Z}$:
$$
(g^n)^{-1} = g^{-n} = (g^{-1})^n
$$
Then for the $n < 0$ case, simply apply your $n > 0$ induction to the element $g^{-1}$.